# How to replace a specific tag content in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, **that may or may not be valid HTML**, but it should contain a Title tag.
I want to replace the content of the title with new content.

Example 1:

```
lorem yada yada <title>Foo</title> ipsum yada yada
```

Should turn into:

```
lorem yada yada <title>Bar</title> ipsum yada yada
```

Example 2:

```
lorem yada yada <title attributeName="value">Foo</title> ipsum yada yada
```

Should turn into:

```
lorem yada yada <title attributeName="value">Bar</title> ipsum yada yada
```

I don't want to parse html with regex - just replace the title tag... Please don't send me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)...

EDIT: 
After numerous down votes and a lot of patronizing attitude -
I am aware (as admitted in the original post) that usually Regex is not the way to handle HTML. I am open to any solution that will solve my problem, but till now every JQuery / DOM solution did not work. Being "right" is not enough.

Comment: This is trivial to do in jQuery. Is that an option?

Comment: @HackedByChinese - No. As I mentioned in the question, I have a string that may not be html.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML="Bar";`

Comment: @seldary I understand that. That fact would not restrict jQuery as an option.

Comment: I'm not editing the page i'm running in! I have a string that the user inputs and I want to manipulate it...

Comment: FYI what you are describing does definitely count as parsing HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *difficult* to do such a thing reliably with regex (read: "will not work for all cases"), thus using some kind of proper parser is best if possible.

That said, here is a simple expression that would work for your examples:

```
var re = /(<title\b[^>]*>)[^<>]*(<\/title>)/i;
str = str.replace(re, "$1Bar$2");
```

Some things that this does not handle and will not work right with: comments, quotes, CDATA, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
function replaceTitle( str, replacement ) {
    var tmp = document.createElement("ihatechrome");
    tmp.innerHTML = str;
    tmp.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = replacement;
    return tmp.innerHTML;   
}

replaceTitle( "lorem yada yada <title>Foo</title> ipsum yada yada", "Bar" );
//"lorem yada yada <title>Bar</title> ipsum yada yada"
```

For some reason, google chrome makes requests if there are `img` tags with `src`. Doesn't make any sense but that's what happens.

Edit:

This seems to work in chrome (does not load images):

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");

doc.body.innerHTML = "<img src='/'>";

doc.body.innerHTML; //"<img src="/">"
```

Comment: Won't this execute any `<script>`s or load images that may be present in the string?

Comment: And will there be any chance that text other than the title's inner text will be changed? even slightly?

Comment: It will load images but not execute scripts or style tags

Comment: @Esailija - This is why I thought of regex... I don't want any side effects. just to replace the string.

Comment: @seldary fine, so use a regex then

Comment: I just checked this with a random html page, and your solution REMOVED the <head> and <html> tags, among some more changes to the original string. I thought it was obvious, but I can't allow this to alter the input beyond the title's content.

Answer (score 0):

Please god don't try and parse html with a regex (I know you said you aren't parsing it, but you are...) jQuery has a perfectly good set of primitives to manipulate html that isn't in the DOM:

```
var htmlishString = "almost <title>HTML</title>";
var $fakeDiv = jQuery('<div />');
$fakeDiv.html(htmlishString).find('title').text('Bar');
var manipulatedString = $fakeDiv.html()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4kQkx/

Comment: Have you tested this? the third line is throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined".

Comment: @seldary it works in chrome, but i did not test in any other browser

Comment: It crashed with this: view-source:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/06/18/implementation-defined-behaviour.aspx

Comment: it also works in FF. Not sure I understand the relevance of that link

Comment: admittedly this also appears to suffer the fetching scripts bug in chrome

Comment: I Ran your code on the html of that page (which contains a <title> tag), and it crashed, while your (rather simple) example worked. It doesn't help me if it fails on real world input, and suffers from bugs.

Comment: @seldary yeah, due to downloading and running scripts which are executed on diff host, thus same-origin policy breaks it...