# Update text within mulitple <a> tags in a string

Tags: jquery, html, text

I can't make the below to return the text string with amended text for `<a>` tags. Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
         var extra = '<a>Abcde</a><a>Bcdefg</a>'
         var extra2 = $(extra).filter('a').each(function(e){
                $(this).text('abc');
         })
```

Every attempt to alert(extra2) results in [object Object]. When I console.log it, I can see the amended text, but I can't just print the desired string

```
<a>abc</a><a>abc</a>
```

Please ignore the above. I found that there's no issue with it anymore after some adjustments with the rest of my code and it works. It doesn't work in a way I'd want it to though. What I'm trying to achieve is

```
var extra = "<a href="http://etc">Abcdefghij</a> how to make it work properly? <a href="http://etc">Defghijk</a>

var extra2 = magic(extra);
```

And in result I'd like to get

```
<a href="http://etc">abc</a> how to make it work properly? <a href="http://etc">abc</a>
```

I will be grateful for any hints.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying change elements in the DOM or are you just trying to replace content of a string? Replacing the contents of a tag in a string has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100077/how-to-replace-a-specific-tag-content-in-javascript

Comment: I'm trying to use twitter fetcher to get a tweet. It has a stupidly long link inside, so, using Jason Mayer's tweeter fetcher, I'm trying to replace the link text with a generic text before it's appended on the website. I thought it's going to be easy, but for some reason I just can't dig it out... I can't just append the updated text on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var extra = 'test<a>Abcde</a><a>Bcdefg</a>';
var $extra2 = $('<div>').append(extra);

$extra2.find('a').each(function(e){   
     $(this).text('abc')
});
```

So $extra2 contains the data you want.
See the docs for more info https://api.jquery.com/each/

edit: use `var extra2 = $extra2.html();` to have the html representation (string)

Comment: I used this approach in the beginning (look at the very top of my post). It still returns [object Object] when I try to print it. Also, when checking console.log, I can see that extra2 only carries the info about <a> and the text inside, but I don't want to lose the rest of the text.

Comment: that is normal, you have a jquery object not a string

Comment: Yeah, but I did ask for help with printing the entire string with replaced text inside of <a> tags.

Comment: Now, despite of multiple links being inside the var extra, it only prints out one link without updated text and gets rid of the rest of the text.

Comment: We're getting there! It works alright, except for the fact that if there's any text in front of first <a> tag, it gets completely removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('a').text('abc');
```

All `<a>` tags will have 'abc' inside